# Eclipse won't recognize the src files from a git import

Tags: java, eclipse, git

I imported a huge repository from gitlab for my lab project. It is structured like this:

```
project_folder [master]   
    JRE System Library  
    main_project_stuff  
    anthome_build_stuff  
    com  
    config  
    doc  
   ...etc
```

Most java projects I have handled are structured like this:

```
project_folder  
   src  
   bin
```

Because there is no source folder, java will not recognize any of these folders for what they are. As a result, it can't build them and give me error messages. This only works when I drag them into a src directory that I make with eclipse, which is not ok with the lab because I can't be reorganizing files on the master branch when I eventually commit to it with git.
So how can I make eclipse recognize these as src .java files that are in packages like package: com.robot.robotComponent.java? Without actually moving them into the src directory manually?

TL;DR How do I make eclipse stop thinking of these as folders and realize they are actually packages that are stored as a folder tree?

Note: This project is not configured to be used only in eclipse, but is a general project. So I have to make my own .project and .classpath files to make it readable to eclipse.

(I am using Ubuntu 14.04 but maybe that is not relevant. I got it to work by brute force making the project_folder the actual src folder, but then there are a bunch of compile errors because the project really isn't meant to necessarily be built in eclipse? It builds from the command line using run-registry command but I want it to at least show me useful errors like when I make newbie mistakes like one too many "}" or forget to implement all functions in an interface, eclipse can fix that automatically for me with a red error message. Now however I am getting many strange errors, like it can't find project_folder.SuperComponent.java which I know is there!)

Update: I guess this needs to run a registry from ant? And then build it from an ant build.xml. I'm not sure how to get the command line arguments to work with eclipse.

Comment: `Java` does not recognize folders, your IDE or project manager does. In Eclipse, go to the project properties window, and select "Java Build Path". On the "Sources" tab you could add your source folders...

Comment: You may try create the folder **src** and create a symbolic link **com -> ../com** inside **src**. That should solve the compilation issues with Eclipse and also keep all the source files in the original place for you to sync with git later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the Eclipse [Smart Import](https://wiki.eclipse.org/E4/UI/Smart_Import) feature, the project will be detected as a Java project (even without the `.project` file) and automatically configured (`.classpath`, etc.). Instead of using *File > Import...* do the following:

1. **Clone** the Git repository
2. In the *Git Repositories* view **right-click** the ***Working Tree*** node and choose ***Import Projects...***

Note, the more up-to-date your Eclipse IDE is, the better the automatic detection and configuration will work.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will try that. Will it detect the ant build.xml file and automatically build from that source? When I run it from the command line I have to say ./ant run-registry and then ./ant run-my-program, which are custom commands specified in the build file. Do you know how I could tell eclipse that, when auto building, it must use those arguments on the build.xml file?

Comment: I assume the Ant file will not be detected. You can use an [Ant build file as project builder](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-92_project_builders.htm) which will run the Ant file on every save/modification of a project file or folder (if that's what you really want).

Comment: Yes, that may be what I need to do. Thank you!